# Background only when booting into i3-gaps on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after installing. Any help?

Tags: 16.04, i3-wm

This is my first time using Ubuntu, so sorry in advance if I don't understand some terminology.

My current plight is whenever I select to log into i3-gaps, it logs in, but then I'm just left with the login background, unable to do anything but move my mouse. No commands I've tried have opened anything, and I've looked around but everyone else seems to have issues with one of the packages, which I haven't had issues with.

Is there something I'm skipping over, or am I not installing it right?

I'm using an HP Pavilion dm4 laptop, and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: i3 is pretty bare bones. You might find [this useful](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/707/menu-in-i3wm.1.html)

Comment: Doest alt+enter or win+enter spawn a terminal?

Comment: @mreq Yep! That did it. Glad that I actually did install it properly. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I installed it correctly, and just didn't realize that the commands were different. Thanks to @mreq for that.
Posting this just so I can say the question was answered if nobody else submits.

Comment: You should see a bar on the bottom of your screen. Seems like the default config doesn't work for you. Try removing `~/.config/i3` and rebooting.